# How in WebFlux to stop publisher when request is aborted by client?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, cancellation

`SpringBoot v2.5.1`

There is an endpoint requesting a long running process result and it is created somehow
(for simplicity it is `Mono.fromCallable( ... long running ... )`.

Client make a request and triggers the publisher to do the work, but after several seconds client  aborts the request (i.e. connection is lost). And the process still continues to utilize resources for computation of a result to throw away.

**What is a mechanism of notifying Project Reactor's event loop about unnecessary work in progress that should be cancelled?**

```
@RestController 
class EndpointSpin {
 
  @GetMapping("/spin")
  Mono<Long> spin() {
    AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
    Instant stopTime = Instant.now().plus(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS));

    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

      while (Instant.now().isBefore(stopTime)) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();

        if (counter.get() % 10_000_000 == 0) {
          System.out.println(counter.get());
        }

        // of course this does not work
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
           break;
        }
      }

      return counter.get();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fromCallable` doesn't shield you from blocking computation inside the `Callable`, which your example demonstrates.

The primary mean of cancellation in Reactive Streams is the `cancel()` signal propagated from downstream via the `Subscription`.

Even with that, the fundamental requirement of avoiding blocking code inside reactive code still holds, because if the operators are simple enough (ie. synchronous), a blocking step could even prevent the propagation of the `cancel()` signal...

A way to adapt non-reactive code while still getting notified about cancellation is `Mono.create`: it exposes a `MonoSink` (via a `Consumer<MonoSink>`) which can be used to push elements to downstream, and at the same time it has a `onCancel` handler.

You would need to rewrite your code to eg. check an `AtomicBoolean` on each iteration of the loop, and have that AtomicBoolean flipped in the sink's `onCancel` handler:

```
Mono.create(sink -> {
    AtomicBoolean isCancelled = new AtomicBoolean();
    sink.onCancel(() -> isCancelled.set(true));
    while (...) {
        ...
        if (isCancelled.get()) break;
    }
});
```

Another thing that is important to note in your example: the `AtomicInteger` is shared state. If you subscribe a second time to the returned `Mono`, both subscriptions will share the counter and increment it / check it in parallel, which is probably not good.

Creating these state variables inside the `Consumer<MonoSink>` of `Mono.create` ensures that each subscription gets its own separate state.